# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solamente me muestre 3 números?

Tags: c, bucle-for

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main ()
{
int i,a,b,c;
printf("NUMEROS DESCENDENTES\n");
printf("DIGITE EL NUMERO CON EL QUE QUIERA EMPEZAR\n");
scanf("%i",&a);
if (a<3){
    printf("El numero tiene que ser mayor a 2");
}
else{
printf("\nNUMEROS DESCENDENTES DESDE EL %i\n",a);
for(i=a;i>=1;i--){
    printf("\n%i",i);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

El programa muestra números descendentes desde el número que de el usuario, pero quiero que solamente muestra 3 números, osea si pongo 5, que muestre 5,4,3 y no 5,4,3,2,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr eso cambia la condicion dentro del `for`. Tienes que indicar mientras `i<=3` para que solo muestre los 3 numeros que quieres. Porque tal como lo tenias la cuenta lo hará hasta que llegue a 1. Prueba esto:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main ()
{
int i,a,b,c;
printf("NUMEROS DESCENDENTES\n");
printf("DIGITE EL NUMERO CON EL QUE QUIERA EMPEZAR\n");
scanf("%i",&a);
if (a<3){
    printf("El numero tiene que ser mayor a 2");
}
else{
printf("\nNUMEROS DESCENDENTES DESDE EL %i\n",a);
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    printf("\n%i",a--);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```